# "Go to school" or go to the school" in context

Tags: articles, definite-article

Let's say I am in school, and my parents want to visit my school to find out how I am doing there. Which one of the following is the most natural way to communicate the idea?

> My parent are going to school.
>
> My parents are going to **the** school.

I think the second one is the way to go as my parents don't study in school, so the use of the definite article is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that (without other context) “to **the** school” would be the preferred alternative to convey the meaning you described.

Your own description shows an even clearer way of communicating your intended meaning:

> My parents are going to visit my school.

I should add too that “my parents are going to school” won’t *always* mean that they are attending school as students themselves. It depends on context. 
For example this is possible:

> My friend asked me, when she saw my parents leaving the house, “Where
>   are they going?”.  I replied, “**My parents are going to school**.
>   They want to talk to my teacher.”

But “going to **my** school” would be more likely even in this context.